# Elastic Search Give an error No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, server

I am start working with elastic search.I successfully install elastic search on my server(Different from application server).But When I try to call Elatic search from my Application server it gives an error 
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException' with message 'No alive nodes found in your cluster'`

When I check Elastic search status it shows **Active**.

How can I call elastic search from my Application server to my Elastic search server.

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $hosts = [
       'ip_address:9200'         // IP + Port
    ];
    $client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();

    $params = [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'type' => 'my_type',
        'id' => 'my_id',
        'body' => ['testField' => 'abc']
    ];

    $response = $client->index($params);
?>
```

**My elasticsearch.yml Settings**

```
    # ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
    #
    # NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
    #       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
    #       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
    #
    # The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
    # the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
    #
    # Please see the documentation for further information on configuration options:
    # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html>
    #
    # ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
    #
    # Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
    #
     cluster.name: my-application
    #
    # ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
    #
    # Use a descriptive name for the node:
    #
     node.name: node-1
    #
    # Add custom attributes to the node:
    #
    # node.rack: r1
    #
    # ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
    #
    # Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
    #
    # path.data: /path/to/data
    #
    # Path to log files:
    #
    # path.logs: /path/to/logs
    #
    # ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
    #
    # Lock the memory on startup:
    #
    # bootstrap.memory_lock: true
    #
    # Make sure that the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable is set to about half the memory
    # available on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this limit.
    #
    # Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
    #
    # ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
    #
    # Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
    #
    #network.host: 0.0.0.0
    #network.bind_host: 0
    #
    # Set a custom port for HTTP:
    #
    # http.port: 9200
    #
    # For more information, see the documentation at:
    # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
    #
    # --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
    #
    # Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
    # The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
    #
    # discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
    #
    # Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 + 1):
    #
    # discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
    #
    # For more information, see the documentation at:
    # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html>
    #
    # ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
    #
    # Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
    #
    # gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
    #
    # For more information, see the documentation at:
    # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-gateway.html>
    #
    # ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
    #
    # Disable starting multiple nodes on a single system:
    #
    # node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
    #
    # Require explicit names when deleting indices:
    #
    # action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

**elasticsearch.yml settings which are not working**

`network.host: 127.0.0.1`

`network.host: 0`

`network.host: 0.0.0.0`

`network.host: IP_Address`

`network.bind_host: 0`

`network.bind_host: IP_Address`

**When I set the above settings then elasticsearch shows the failed status.**

**NOTE : Elastic search install on different server from my Application sever.**

Comment: have you added `network.bind_host: 0` in your config file to enable listening from other than localhost?

Comment: try adding `network.bind_host: IP_of_your_elastic_search_server` in  `elasticsearch.yml` ,restart elastic search service and try http://ip:9200 from your application server

Comment: @Kamran Sir when I set network.bind_host: 0 OR network.bind_host: IP_of_your_elastic_search_server and then check  elasticsearch status its show Failed.When I comment "#network.bind_host: 0" then its show Active.

Comment: stop elasticsearch service, add `network.host: 0.0.0.0` start service again.

Comment: and don't forget to put your elsaticsearch server ip in the   `$hosts = ['ip_address:9200'];` array

Comment: @Kamran Current elasticsearch.yml Settings
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.bind_host: IP_ ADDRESS

Elastic Search Status
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-03-02 08:37:28 UTC; 1min 48s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co

Comment: please remove `network.bind_host: IP_ ADDRESS`

Comment: @Kamran comment network.bind_host: IP_ ADDRESS.But same result. status Failed.

Comment: share your `elasticsearch.yml` file

Comment: cluster.name: my-application

node.name: node-1

# node.rack: r1

# path.logs: /path/to/logs

# bootstrap.memory_lock: true

network.host: 0.0.0.0

#network.bind_host: 0

# http.port: 9200

# discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]

# discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3

# gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3

# node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1

# action.destructive_requires_name: true

Comment: @Kamran cluster.name: my-application node.name: node-1 # node.rack: r1 # path.logs: /path/to/logs # bootstrap.memory_lock: true network.host: 0.0.0.0 #network.bind_host: 0 # http.port: 9200 # discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"] # discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3 # gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3 # node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1 # action.destructive_requires_name: true

Comment: @Kamran elasticsearch.yml has been added Please look into this and suggest what changes are required in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error.Error is coming due to space before **node.name** and **cluster.name**.Remove the space and its working fine.

**Updated elasticsearch.yml file**

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please see the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: my-application-shakedeal
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: shakedeal-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
# node.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
# path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
# path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
# bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable is set to about half the memory
# available on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 127.0.0.1
network.bind_host: IP_ADDRESS
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
# http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
# discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 + 1):
#
# discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
# gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-gateway.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Disable starting multiple nodes on a single system:
#
# node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
# action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

**PHP Code**

```
 <?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $indexParams = [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'body' => [
            'settings' => [
                'number_of_shards' => 5,
                'number_of_replicas' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
        ->setSSLVerification(false)
        ->setHosts(["IP_ADDRESS:9200"])->build();  
    $response = ''; 
    try {
        /* Create the index */
        $response = $client->indices()->create($indexParams);
        print_r($response);

        print_r($response);

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception : ".$e->getMessage();
    }
    die('End : Elastic Search');

?>
```

**Success Response** :

```
 Array
 (
    [acknowledged] => 1
 )
```

Comment: But where is " elasticsearch.yml " file i tired to find this one but i doesn't get any type of this file so please know me where it is... thanks

Comment: @Yagneshbhalala It is most likely at /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml If not, try typing `updatedb` on the command line then `locate elasticsearch|grep elasticsearch.yml`

Answer (score 2):

I have found this error and solved it by following steps:

1. Comments the plugin setting on app/etc/env.php file.

   ```
   'system' => [
   'default' => [
     /* 'smile_elasticsuite_core_base_settings' => [
    'es_client' => [
     'servers' => 'node-1:9200,node-2:9200',
     'enable_https_mode' => '0',
     'enable_http_auth' => '0',
     'http_auth_user' => '',
     'http_auth_pwd' => ''
      ]
     ] */
    ]
   ]
   ```
2. Start the server.
3. upgrade magento

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I also facing the same problem. I was specified in host 'myhostaddress:9200'. Change it with IP of your Elasticsearch host server like '127.0.0.1:9200' . It resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, S.O is also used as a keyword-based reference for the Community years later. Therefore I'm jumping in to add an important discovery I made about resolving this `No alive nodes found in your cluster` message:
If you guys are trying to connect to ES Cloud using PHP for example, and are getting this exact message, whereas you've been following the `Elasticsearch PHP Client > Connecting documentation section`, and in particular, trying to connect via the CloudId:

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
   ->setElasticCloudId('<cloud-id>')
   ->setBasicAuthentication('<username>', '<password>')
   ->build();
```

Well you should try to add CA Bundle verification:

```
$caBundle = \Composer\CaBundle\CaBundle::getBundledCaBundlePath();
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
            ->setElasticCloudId($ES_CloudID)
            ->setSSLVerification($caBundle)
            ->setBasicAuthentication($ES_username, $ES_password)
            ->build();
```

I demonstrated that commenting out `->setSSLVerification($caBundle)` makes the construction fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer can be found at the link I am providing https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230626
I got the same problem but through this link it resolved, the answer which suggest attaching a suffix :443 at the end will work

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing slash in elastic search. Sometimes it creates error.

Atleast in my case I removing the trailing slash from Amazon ES URL make it working.