# Laravel: Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run Elasticsearch in a Laravel application.
I'm running at localhost http://127.0.0.1:8000

My elasticsearch is Succesfully started and I all installations are succesfully done..though still get the error:

```
No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

in .env file:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=localhost
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200
ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME=http
ELASTICSEARCH_CORE_SUFFIX=dev2
```

part of my app.php:

```
'providers' => [

/*
 * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
 */
Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
/*
 * Package Service Providers...
 */
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

/*
 * Application Service Providers...
 */
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

Mews\Captcha\CaptchaServiceProvider::class,
Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,

],
'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
    'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Captcha' => Mews\Captcha\Facades\Captcha::class,
    'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,
],
```

cmd command: `curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/
gives following:

```
{
  "name" : "aNRDi3G",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_stevengerrits",
  "cluster_uuid" : "VPxXtDDDAa7rJ71dW3rwA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.6.0",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "a9861f4",
    "build_date" : "2019-01-24T11:27:09.439740Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
`
```

cmd command:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'

{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_stevengerrits",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

installed applications:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.19",
        "cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch": "^2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.5",
        "mews/captcha": "^2.1",
        "spatie/calendar-links": "^1.0",
        "webpatser/laravel-countries": "dev-master#33767373"
    },
```

when i run `brew services restart elasticsearch`

i get:

```
 Successfully started `elasticsearch` (label: homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch)
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549586/elastic-search-give-an-error-no-alive-nodes-found-in-your-cluster) thread if it helps..

Comment: what version of Laravel is this?

Comment: hello, version 5.5

Comment: The repo says *If you are using ElasticSearch version 5, then install version 2 of this package:* you are using version 2 but your ES version is 6.6. Try upgrading

Comment: I see, strange.. I installed version 5.5 i though.. need to downgrade then. It needs to be compatible with an application used by partner

Comment: @apokryfos when using 5.5, elasticsearch won't start up..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809545/elasticsearch-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-9200-connection-refused?noredirect=1#comment96397021_54809545

Comment: I don't know about that. Maybe you can try asking at https://superuser.com/ since that seems more like a software issue rather than a programming issue. I would recommend though to make extra sure that 6.6 is completely purged from your system before installing 5.5 in case of conflicts. Also make sure 5.5 is reading  the correct config which compatible options (in case it was trying to read 6.6 and there were options it didn't recognise)

Comment: I solved it by just running the 5.5 without brew

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the elastic nodes/host in your .env?? And is this also running??

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/
```

Comment: command return:

{
  "name" : "aNYBe3G",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_stefgeits",
  "cluster_uuid" : "VPxXtPDDDAa7rJ71dW3rwA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.6.0",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "a9861f4",
    "build_date" : "2019-01-24T11:27:09.439740Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: i added .env host inf in question

Comment: I do not see the Provider in your app,php ```
Cviebrock\LaravelElasticsearch\ServiceProvider::class

to your list of providers and:

'Elasticsearch' => Cviebrock\LaravelElasticsearch\Facade::class

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running a ES via terminal

Comment: Hi, how did you do that ?