# There is not elasticsearch.yml in windows

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I coding in laravel 5.8 and trying to use of elasticquent search for searching.

I follow this level for my purpose:
https://appdividend.com/2018/06/30/laravel-elasticsearch-tutorial-example/

I get error **"Not alive nodes found in your cluster"**.so I saw this question in stack: [Elastic Search Give an error No alive nodes found in your cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549586/elastic-search-give-an-error-no-alive-nodes-found-in-your-cluster)

But I have not **elasticsearch.yml** file for setting.

Comment: What keeps you from creating such a file?

Comment: @NicoHaase , I am not sure about usage and cause of creating this file but perhaps when elasticsearch setups this file creates too.