# How to replace Escaper class in a specific Block in Magento2

Tags: magento2

**Goal**

Upgrade/rewrite the Magento\Framework\Escaper class only for one block in Magento2.

I need to do this because Magento is converting a “-” character in the conversion label to “\u002”. I think it is a bug in Magento 2 because Google is using "-".

**My solution**

Using dependency injection, a (virtual type) context class is built and a custom escaper injected inside. Then, virtual context is used for a Magento\GoogleAdwords\Block\Code.

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="AdwordsContext" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="escaper" xsi:type="object">MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Escaper</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\GoogleAdwords\Block\Code">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="context" xsi:type="object">AdwordsContext</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Model/Escaper.php

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Model;

class Escaper extends \Magento\Framework\Escaper
{
    /**
     * @param string $string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function escapeJs($string): string
    {
        if ($string === '' || ctype_digit($string)) {
            return $string;
        }

        return preg_replace_callback(
            '/[^a-z0-9,\._-]/iSu',
            function ($matches) {
                $chr = $matches[0];
                if (strlen($chr) != 1) {
                    $chr = mb_convert_encoding($chr, 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8');
                    $chr = ($chr === false) ? '' : $chr;
                }

                return sprintf('\\u%04s', strtoupper(bin2hex($chr)));
            },
            $string
        );
    }
}
```

The module is enabled and *setup:di:compile* and *cache:flush* has been executed.

**The Problem**

Unfortunately, it is not working and still old Magento\Framework\Escaper is used. I can't find a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your elasticsearch configuration and look for more solutions at: [Elastic Search Give an error No alive nodes found in your cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549586/elastic-search-give-an-error-no-alive-nodes-found-in-your-cluster)

Comment: Why do you spam?