# No alive nodes found in your clusterEnd

Tags: php, laravel

```
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();   //connect with the client
    $params = array();
    $params['body']  = array(   
      'name' => "demo",                                             //preparing structred data
      'age' => 25
      
    );
    $params['index'] = 'tests';
    $params['type']  = 'test';
    $result = $client->index($params);                          //using Index() function to inject the data
    var_dump($result);
```

Elastic Search Give an error No alive nodes found in your cluster

Comment: Did you try solutions from other SO solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42594611/13933721 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elastic Search Give an error No alive nodes found in your cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549586/elastic-search-give-an-error-no-alive-nodes-found-in-your-cluster)